# How to pull commits from another computer ? (from Azure DevOps)

Tags: azure, devops, commit

I man a C# project from both my work computer and home computer.

I created the project from my work laptop, and pushed the commits to the DevOps repo before going home. I cloned the repo from DevOps so I can continue working on the program from the home computer later that night after pulling the commit that I done from the workplace. Did another commit before ending the work for the day.

Now, here is the question. as I am going to continue working tomorrow at my workplace. Because the project was created in my work computer, and I am afraid that if I pull the commits from the home computer, there may be conflicts if I screw up with something. What is the safest way to pull the commit to a previous machine (the project folder of the workplace PC, that is) without any conflicts? Again, I am new to Azure DevOps. I will add any more information if you want to.

(For pulling to new machines, I am more comfortable with it. I'm more concerned with pulling to previous machines after working from a newer computer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't leave any uncomitted changes in your work computer if you plan to continue working from home. Commit and push to Az Devops your current stand before continuing from another computer.

Comment: Thanks. If I want to continue working from my work PC, I just pull the commit done from my home PC as usual? (I already committed once before I went home)

Comment: Yes, a "git pull".